# Natural satellites sorted by albedo

Tags: natural-satellites, albedo

Can I find a list of natural satellites of the Solar System with the average albedo for each one ?

Enceladus, for instance has an albedo of [0.81](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enceladus) and Triton has an albedo of [0.76](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triton_(moon)). But has someone already made a table with the albedo for each moon in the Solar System ?

Comment: not a complete one, but you may find some at `https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_albedo`

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a list, but Horizons has geometric albedo of the major satellites, eg https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=NO&COMMAND=602 Here are the IDs of all major bodies: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=NO&COMMAND=MB

Comment: The Minor Planet Center gives phase and magnitude, which you could use to compute the albedo. https://minorplanetcenter.net/iau/NatSats/NaturalSatellites.html

Answer (score 1):

For moons of Jupiter you may look at [this compilation from NASA](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/joviansatfact.html). The icy or sulfurous surfaces of three of the Galilean satellites stand out in this system.